# Tailwind: same space before and after divider line

Tags: css, user-interface, tailwind-css

I am trying to have the same space (and configurable) before and after the divider line. However I cannot seem to get the spacing after the divider line.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 divide-y divide-solid">
   <div class="pb-5">Hello</div>
   <div class="pb-5">World</div>
   <div class="pb-5">hi</div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How can I get the same spacing before and after the divider line? Ideally without needing to touch the children styles (i.e. remove the pb-#)?

Comment: Make `pb-5` `py-2`?

Comment: Also, if they had been `pt-5`, then you could have added `gap-5` to `.grid`.

Comment: @brc-dd py-2 works except then the first and last item has padding-top and padding-bottom respectively. Is there a way to remove the padding-top from first and padding-bottom from last?

Comment: You can try something like this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/wIErADXAjp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code,

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 divide-y divide-solid bg-gray-500">
        <div class="py-2  first:pt-0">Hello</div>
        <div class="py-2">World</div>
        <div class=" py-2 last:pb-0">hi</div>
</div>
```

[image]

credits: @brc-dd [sample](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wIErADXAjp)